# Swift Firebase - getting multiple uid's then adding those uid's to a child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been thinking about this but I thought I'd post a question to get some more thinking power behind this or to see if this is even possible. I am grabbing multiple uid's and then want to take these uid's and append them to a child in my database and then add further data to them. Since they are uid's I can't access them separately which would be a easy firebase "update values" call, so how could I take this list of uid's and then add them to a child so they are their own separate children and then add values to them? I am just thinking about how I would set this firebase call to say "add each one of these uid's as its own child".

**How I am getting the uid's**

```
func getEmployees() {
   let employees =  Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child(self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String).child("registered_employees").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            let employess = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid")
            print(employess)
        } else {
            print("didnt call right values")
        }
    })
}
```

**sample of data I would add to uid child**

```
let userMessageRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(fromID).child(toID)
        let messageId = childRef.key
        userMessageRef.updateChildValues([messageId!:1])
```

The code right above ^^^^ I would want the uid's to be in "toID" and then adding the "messageId" to those uid's

I don't know how I could even do each uid separately in the call because of the inability to extract each one and then set the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand so let me try an answer with an example. How we obtain the uid's we want to write is not outlined in the question so let try this:

Suppose we have a users node that stores our users and if they like pizza

```
users
   uid_0 //the Firebase generated uid
      name: "Richie"
      likes_pizza: true
   uid_1
      name: "Marion"
      likes_pizza: false
   uid_2
      name: "Fonzi"
      likes_pizza: true
   uid_3
      name: "Howard"
      likes_pizza: false
```

what we want to do it to get the users that like pizza, craft a new node and store each of the uid's as a parent and then a child of their name.

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
let pizzaQueryRef = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "likes_pizza").queryEqual(toValue: true)
pizzaQueryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    guard let allUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
    for user in allUsers {
        let key = user.key
        let name = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
        let pizzaRef = self.ref.child("pizza_lovers")
        let aPizzaLoverRefUid = pizzaRef.child(key).child("their_name")
        aPizzaLoverRefUid.setValue(name)
    }
})
```

so this code queries for all users that like pizza (which enables us to access their uid's), and then (per the question) append them to a child in the database and then add further data to them

> and then want to take these uid's and append them to a child in my
>   database and then add further data to them

the result is

```
pizza_lovers
   uid_0
      their_name: "Richie"
   uid_2
      their_name: "Fonzi"
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the question and I will update.